# how to create SIP uri using java.net.URI class?

Tags: java, uri, sip, voip

The server or you can say VOIP provider is `ekiga.net`.
I want to call this contact `sip:500@ekiga.net`. I have created sip headers as defined in `rfc3261` and I want to create a sip uri using `URI` class. This is what I need help with.

The Purpose for creating uri is to send the udp packet that contains sip headers and messages to the server. I don't know what address to use because `DataGram` class needs destination ip and port. I know the port is 5060 but I don't know which url to use.

Thanks

Comment: Corrected grammatical errors and added more tags

Answer (score 0):

Java don't have built-in support for SIP, so you don't need java for SIP URI.

Optionally first you might perform a DNS lookup like this:

```
InetAddress inetAddress =  InetAddress.getByName("ekiga.net");
```

(this will lookup A record only. For VoIP you should use SRV DNS records, but that requires a seprate lib and A record is usually just fine)

Then create an UDP socket like this:

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
```

Then send any message like this (buff must hold a valid SIP message):

```
socket.send(new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length,  InetAddress.getByName("ekigaaddresshere"), 5060));
```

Then read the answer(s) and send other requests.